# iPhone - Sybase connectivity

Tags: iphone

I am trying to fetch data from SAP to iPhone with Sybase unwired platform.
I am able to see my iPhone simulator in sybase control center.I can see online and offline status of my application.But I am not able to see any data in my iPhone simulator.
I run debug and noticed that `loginSuccessCount` from `defaultCallBackHandler` doesn't go above 1.
I tried many username and passwords starting from sup and s3p accordingly.

Can any one give some idea?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but having the same problem. How did you fix this (if you did)?

Comment: Hi ggfela, how did u fix this, can u share with us